# Xbox API JSON request on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, json, api, jsonp, xbox

I'm trying to use the Unofficial Xbox API to request a JSON string and then process that using VB.NET.

Here is the link; [Unofficial Xbox API](https://xboxapi.com/)

Using the below code I've managed to successfully load the data using Firefox, but IE returns and "Access Denied" error; which I guess is due to this being a cross-domain request using JSON not JSONP.

Is there any way I can get around this? Even if it's to load the entire JSON string. I tried to use JSONP, but the data is in an incorrect format for that.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://xboxapi.com/json/profile/RTriggerHappy',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#txtUsernameJS').val(data.Player.Gamertag);
                    $('#txtGamerScoreJS').val(data.Player.Gamerscore);
                    alert("worked");
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(status + ", " + error);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your JSON in PHP instead of Javascript, this will prevent the "Access Denied" message in IE.